# How do you restrict access to a server to be from a single machine (which doesn't have a dedicated IP)?

Tags: networking, centos, security, remote-access

We want to deploy a J2EE WAR file from a build server to an application server (running JBoss 7.1.1) using the JBoss management console.  Each machine is located on a different network.  On the build server, we are using Jenkins to run build scripts.  The problem is the build server doesn't have a dedicated IP (hosted at Cloudbees) and we would also like to restrict to the application server so that only the build server can deploy to it.

My question is, what methods are available to us regarding securing access to our application server from our build server?  Although our application server is hosted on Amazon, that is not a guarantee going forward, although it is a guarantee that we will be hosted on some type of CentOS distribution.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Sure would be nice if IPv6 was a thing, since IPSEC is built-in.

Answer (score 6):

Without a dedicated IP, you have to fall back on implementing some sort of certificate authentication (which can be copied from one machine to another) or username / password authentication (which an be used on any machine in the world). In short, the problem you're trying to solve is extremely difficult to solve, if it's even solvable at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the certificate authentication?  How can I place something on my build server (client) that can then be recognized by the server?

Answer (score -1):

What about using hostnames and resolving to a dynamic IP?

Comment: The IP most likely can't be reverse-resolved. So You can't do it that way. Or, if you simply trust the hostname the workstation gives you, then anyone in the world can impersonate you, giving you less security than before since you think you're secure and so become complacent.